# Perl CGI persistent cookies

Tags: perl, cgi

I want the user to non have to login even if the browser was closed. My cookies are set to expire after a month.

when the user logs in sucessfully

```
 $session = CGI::Session->new (undef, undef, {Directory=>'tmp/'})
                                      or die CGI::Session->errstr;
                $session->param('username', $username);
                $session->expire('+1M');                
                $cookie = $cgi->cookie( -name=>$session->name, -value=>$session->id );
                print $cgi->header(-cookie=>$cookie );
```

They are then redirected to another page that they can access as long as they don't close the browser. This is the code in the second page:

```
my $cookie = $cgi->cookie('CGISESSID');
if ($cookie){
        print $cgi->header(-cookie => $cookie);
else{
       //ask them to relog in
}
```

I can see the sessions created in tmp/. How do I load an existing cookie after the browser is closed. How do I know which session to load based on the user/browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you set a future expiration date on your cookies, they should persist even after a user restarts their browser (as long as they restart before that date, of course). To load the cookie, do exactly what you're doing:

```
my $cookie = $cgi->cookie('CGISESSID');
```

To try to load an existing session using the cookie you can simply pass your CGI object to the `new` method of CGI::Session:

```
my $session = new CGI::Session(undef, $cgi, {Directory=>"/tmp"});
```

This will attempt to initialize an existing session using the cookie passed in with the CGI request; if one doesn't exist, it will create a new session. Note that this assumes the cookie name is `CGISESSID`. To use another name, run:

```
CGI::Session->name("MY_SID");
# or
$session->name("MY_SID");

$session = new CGI::Session(undef, $cgi, {Directory=>'/tmp'});
```

If you haven't already, I would recommend reading through the [CGI::Session tutorial](http://search.cpan.org/~sherzodr/CGI-Session-3.95/Session/Tutorial.pm).

---

**EDIT:** The session was set to expire in one month

```
$session->expire('+1M');
```

but the cookie was not. If you don't set an expiration on a cookie, the browser will store it in memory but not on disk; as soon as you close the browser, the cookie disappears. To set the cookie expiration, do something like

```
$cookie = $cgi->cookie( -name=>$session->name, -value=>$session->id, -expires=>'+1M' );
```

Comment: Thank you. I have read the documentation which is why I am not sure why my $cookie = $cgi->cookie('CGISESSID'); is not returning anything? I am creating a new cgi object in the second file, maybe thats why?

Comment: @Jabda Have you checked that your browser actually receives the cookie and that it has the correct session ID? In Firefox you can do this by going to `Edit->Preferences->Privacy->remove individual cookies`. You are presented with a list of all stored cookies, organized by site. There is also a search function.

Comment: Yes I see the cookies but only before I close the browser. After I reopen the browser and navigate back to the page, there are no cookies in the browser ( they are in /tmp)

Comment: @Jabda Two other things to check: 1) What is `expires` set to when you view the cookie in your browser? 2) Can you view the cookie after you restart your browser but *before* navigating back to your CGI? Your CGI code might be deleting the cookie.

Comment: After checking what expire is set to I realized it set "browser session" I was setting the session -expire=>'+1M' but I need to set the cookie to not expire either!
$cookie = $cgi->cookie( -name => $session->name, -value => $session->id , -expires => '+1M');

Comment: @Jabda Ah, I didn't catch that in your code snippet. I'll add that to my answer in case somebody runs into this in the future.